# Pandas binned data into df's

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a CSV file of time series data which is one column labeled `oatSensor` (outside air temperature sensor filtered based on conditions from a different process), and I looking for a way to bin the data on a "per day" basis if its possible.

For example, I can bin the entire data set just fine with this code below. For outside air temperature values on increments of -5 to 55.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ahu1OatFiltHourFilt.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df.describe()

cats = ['-5--1',
        '0-4','5-9','10-14','15-19','20-24',
        '25-29','30-34','35-39','40-44','45-49','50-54']
bins = [-5, 0,
        5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35,
       40, 45, 50, 55]

df2 = (df.groupby([df.index, pd.cut(df['oatSensor'], bins, labels=cats)])
            .size()
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
            .reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0))

df2.sum(axis = 0)
```

Which will output this:

```
oatSensor

-5--1      3
0-4        6
5-9       19
10-14     49
15-19     65
20-24    125
25-29    230
30-34    201
35-39    171
40-44    205
45-49    179
50-54    183
dtype: int64
```

But ultimately I am hoping to figure out a way:

1) Create separate df columns for each bin category `cats`
`df4 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=cats)`

2) re-sample the entire dataframe per `day` for a `sum` of each bin

Hopefully that makes, the data I am using is in this [git repo](https://github.com/bbartling/Data/blob/master/ahu1OatFiltHourFilt.csv).

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
If i use a `df3 = df2.stack()` this gives me what I am looking for with the exception of be resampling, but how would I implementing creating separate `cats` dataframes which could then be resampled for a sum per day?

```
Date                 oatSensor
2018-09-26 05:00:00  -5--1        0
                     0-4          0
                     5-9          0
                     10-14        0
                     15-19        0
                     20-24        0
                     25-29        0
                     30-34        0
                     35-39        0
                     40-44        0
                     45-49        0
                     50-54        1
2018-09-26 06:00:00  -5--1        0
                     0-4          0
                     5-9          0
                     10-14        0
                     15-19        0
                     20-24        0
                     25-29        0
                     30-34        0
                     35-39        0
                     40-44        0
                     45-49        0
                     50-54        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a dataframe where each row is a sum of the number of observations seen within the bins you have described, indexed by the day the observations were taken.

If that's true, then I think you are super, super close!

Change

`df2 = (df.groupby([df.index, pd.cut(df['oatSensor'], bins, labels=cats)])
            .size()
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
            .reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0))`

to read:

`df2 = (df.groupby([df.index.date, pd.cut(df['oatSensor'], bins, labels=cats)])
            .size()
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
            .reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0))`

The change is adding `.date` to the first argument in the `groupby`. This will give you a dataframe like I described above.

I'm not sure this gets to your point about separate dataframes for each `cat`. From the dataframe *I've* created, you could create a new df for any of the columns simply by:

`df_cat = df2['-5--1']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Good luck ;)

```
import pandas as pd

distance = 5
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/ahu1OatFiltHourFilt.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
min = df.oatSensor.min()
max = df.oatSensor.max()
min = int(min - (min % distance))
max = int(max + distance - (max % distance))
labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + distance) for i in range(min, max, 
distance)]
df['group'] = pd.cut(df.oatSensor, range(min, max + distance, distance), 
right=False, labels=labels)
df2 = df.groupby(['group']).count()
df['one'] = 1
df3 = df.pivot_table('one','Date','group')
print(df3.tail())
```

out:

```
# group                -5 - 0  0 - 5  5 - 10  ...  85 - 90  90 - 95  95 - 100
# Date                                        ...                            
# 2019-07-06 13:00:00     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
# 2019-07-06 14:00:00     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
# 2019-07-06 15:00:00     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
# 2019-07-06 16:00:00     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN
# 2019-07-09 15:00:00     NaN    NaN     NaN  ...      1.0      NaN       NaN
```